# Can I add new properties to event that is triggered from code

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

in this demo if you click on #s2 the append will execute twice, but if you click on the button which triggers a click on #s2 the append will execute just once, because I can't add new properties to the event when it is triggered from code it.  Is this intended behavior?

(I know that if I use `e.originalEvent.handled` instead of `e.handled` it works the same both ways)

http://jsbin.com/tirufoqa/1/edit

```
<div>
  <span id='s1'>click s1</span>
  <div>
    <span id='s2'>click s2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$('div').on('click', 'span', function(e){
  if(e.handled) return;
  e.handled = 1;
  $(this).append("*");
});

$('button').click(function(){

  $('#s2').click();
});
```

Comment: It's appending twice because the `divs` are nested...this is without nesting http://jsbin.com/jecetaxe/1/edit

Comment: @Dan, I know, this is done on purpose, I'm adding a new property to the event, note `e.handled = 1`, the event propagates and when the second div handles it does return; note `if(e.handled) return;`, what am saying is that the property handled is created only when the event is triggered from code

Comment: Got it...I see what you mean.

Comment: @Omu, did one of our responses point you to your answer? Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

That's really interesting.  I think I found an answer, but it took some digging.

Just to test, I added the following lines to your code:

Outside your handlers:

```
var firstEvent = null;
```

Inside your `div` handler:

```
alert(e === firstEvent);
firstEvent = e;
```

When you manually click on the span, the second time through this comparison is `false`; but when you trigger the click with jQuery, the second time through this comparison is `true`.  See [here](http://jsbin.com/tirufoqa/3/edit?html,css,js,output).

In the jQuery file itself, around line 4715, there's the following line:

```
if ( event[ jQuery.expando ] ) {
    return event;
}
```

What this basically means is that if `event` is already a jQuery.Event object, then it returns that already existing jQuery.Event object; whereas if it is not currently a jQuery.Event object, then it makes a new jQuery.Event object that contains the same properties as the original event.

In your first example, <strike>two events are fired by the browser, and in each case jQuery makes a new jQuery.Event object out of it.  You end up with two jQuery.Event objects.</strike>

EDIT: There is only one event fired by the browser, but that one event is passed by the browser to each div's handler in its native form, rather than as a jQuery.Event object, and a new jQuery.Event object is made by copying the event's properties.

In the second example, jQuery is simulating the event.  The first time through, it creates a jQuery.Event object; the second time through, it already has a jQuery.Event object from the first simulation, and so it uses that rather than making a new one.

EDIT: jQuery "triggers" events by calculating the eventPath a given event *would* take and then simulating the event at that level by calling the handler with `.apply(cur, data)`, which makes `this` equal to the current element in the "bubble up" and passes as `data` all of the information *it* has received, including a jQuery.Event object that simulates the native event.  The same `data` is passed to each element's handler bubbling up the DOM (until it is told to stop bubbling or reaches the top)

The upshot is that whereas with an actual click, jQuery creates a new jQuery.Event object at each level of the bubble-up, in this case the same jQuery.Event object is passed to each level, and thus any properties that you add at a lower level will still be there at a higher level.

Comment: I see so it's different jquery events, don't think the browser is  firing 2 events though, if you change the e to e.originalEvent http://jsbin.com/tirufoqa/6/edit you'll get 'false true' both ways

Comment: @Omu You're right. I'll look into it more tomorrow to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to limit the number of asterisks appended to `span#s2` to be the same as the number of clicks on `span#s2`?

The event-handling function fires twice when you click the `span#s2` because it's nested within two divs, and each div is connected to your event-listener.

You can stop this propagation by adding this invocation to the first line of your event-handling function:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/pobig/1/

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation